# Binning pandas dataframe and converting to a JSON

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group the pandas data frame into bins and then get their count and then convert it to a JSON.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df.columns = ['id']
bins = np.arange(0, 100, 20)
gp = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['id'], bins)).count()
gp.to_json()
```

The convert to JSON part throws the following exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 875, in to_json
    default_handler=default_handler)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 35, in to_json
    date_unit=date_unit, default_handler=default_handler).write()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 78, in write
    default_handler=self.default_handler)
ValueError: Label array sizes do not match corresponding data shape
```

My data values are

```
[100L, 118L, 39L, 132L, 101L, 82L, 478L, 1751L, 1066L, 598L, 141L, 113L, 2945L, 326L, 0L, 62L, 197L, 63L, 1254L, 33L, 519L, 134L, 95L, 41L]
```

The resulting output is not MultiIndex , I am not sure why this error.

Comment: I proposed you this solution but i do not know if it's the wanted json.

Comment: great, glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
# insert bins in a new oclumn
df['bin']=pd.cut(df['id'], bins)

# count per group of bin and convert category to strings
res = df.groupby('bin').count().reset_index()
res['bin']=res['bin'].apply(str)

res.to_json(orient='records')
#Out[24]: '[{"bin":"(0, 20]","id":0},{"bin":"(20, 40]","id":2},{"bin":"(40, 60]","id":1},{"bin":"(60, 80]","id":2}]'
```